# cast from 'BYTE* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'DWORD {aka long unsigned int}' loses precision [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

im trying to add an address to a module base address

```
HANDLE  snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pId); 
   MODULEENTRY32 module; 
   module.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32); 
   Module32First(snapshot, &module); 


   CloseHandle(snapshot); 
      DWORD addr = 0x1D4192 + (DWORD)module.modBaseAddr;
```

i don't know what is wrong

Comment: C++ /commenttooshort

Comment: On a 64-bit systems pointers are usually 64 bits wide. `int` (and therefore `unsigned int`) is usually only 32 bits wide. Now think about what happens when you try to cast a 64-bit value to a 32-bit value.

Comment: Unless your platform supports unaligned load/store operations, `0x1D4192` doesn't look like a valid offset to be accessed via a 32-bit (or larger) pointer.

Comment: Yep code works now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, pointers vary in size depending on the platform (64 bits or 32 bits), while integers (int, long, long int...) are usually 32 bits in both. Casting a pointer to an integer may produce a loose of precision in 64 bits compilations, that's the reason of the warning.